# Cannot post to group using test user in app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group, facebook-permissions

Logged in as Test User to post to group in app while in development mode, but failed.

According to this bug report
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/374244166706163/
It works only when I'm an admin of both the app and group.

To request Groups API permission in App review section, I have to reproduce my application's functionalities using a test user.
How am I supposed to do that if my developer account is the only one able to successfully post to group?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, feature got cancelled because we couldn't wait any longer for Facebook support to respond.

Comment: I also have this issue. My app works if I myself post to my group, but that doesn't let the Facebook team test the functionality.. I think I'll  be submitting for review as-is and let the Facebook team tell me if they need more. I'll post a solution here if I am able to get my app approved.